# iphone:access default calendar and reminder on button click event

Tags: xcode

How to retrieve default calendar and reminder programmatically in ios, I have one simple project which have one button ,i want click on button to access the default reminder and calendar

I have done simple code for that but it is nort working properly
following is the my sample code

```
 #import "ViewController.h"
 #import <EventKit/EventKit.h>

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController   
- (IBAction)btn:(id)sender {
    EKEventStore *eventStore=[[EKEventStore alloc]init];
    EKEvent *event =[EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    NSDate *startDate=[[NSDate alloc]init];
    NSDate *endDate =[[NSDate alloc]init];

    event.title=@"Title for new event";
    event.startDate=startDate;
    event.endDate=endDate;
    event.allDay=YES;
    [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err;
    [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent  error:&err];   

   //   if (err == noErr){
  //        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Event create" message:@"how about that?" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"okey" otherButtonTitles:nil];

//       

//       [alert show];
}
```

When I'm running it on iphone 4s reale device on that time it show's me the following error:

> ```
> 2013-03-13 09:52:22.638 remind[774:907] defaultCalendarForNewEvents
> failed: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "The operation
> couldn’t be completed. (EKCADErrorDomain error 1013.)"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
 this is my .h header file where u have to declare this below code:
 uikit framework

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>

#define ALERT_Reminder 0

@interface GaSchedulesDeWorming : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, EKEventEditViewDelegate>

{

 EKEventStore *eventStore;



}


this ins my implementation file .m:

          **#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>**
add these package
```

this below code is for open the by default calender for set the reminde in ipone

```
     EKEventStore *eventStore=[[EKEventStore alloc]init];
     EKEvent *event =[EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
     NSDate *startDate=[[NSDate alloc]init];
     NSDate *endDate =[[NSDate alloc]init];

     event.title=@"Title for new event";
     event.startDate=startDate;
     event.endDate=endDate;
     event.allDay=YES;
     [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
     NSError *err;
     [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent  error:&err];   


     eventStore=[[EKEventStore alloc]init];

      __block BOOL accessGranted = NO;



     if([eventStore   respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {

       dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

       [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

       accessGranted = granted;

       dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);

       }];

       dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

        } else {



       accessGranted = YES;

        }



        if (accessGranted) {



        }





        EKEventEditViewController *controller = [[EKEventEditViewController  alloc]init];









    }
```